# One-To-Many Query Tuples

Tags: sql, jpa

I have an an Entity1 with a one-to-many relationship to Entity2.
Entity2 stores properties and has the fields "key" and "value".

Now I need to query all Entity1's which have certain key/value combinations (AND logic)

```
SELECT e1 FROM Entity1 e Join e.props e2 
WHERE 
e2.key = :key1 and e2.value = :value1
And
e2.key = :key2 and e2.value = :value2 -- wont work
```

Comment: Maybe "e2.key = :key1 and e2.value = :value1 OR e2.key = :key2 and e2.value = :value2" ?

Comment: @Multisync, it won't check for _combination_ of properties.

Answer (score 1):

One way that easily generalizes to more key/value pairs is to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT entity_id
FROM e.props
GROUP BY entity_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN e2.key = :key1 and e2.value = :value1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN e2.key = :key2 and e2.value = :value2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

For more conditions, you can just add more clauses to the `having`.

Answer (score 1):

JPA understands EXISTS:

```
SELECT e1 FROM Entity1 e1 
WHERE exists (select 1 from Entity2 e2 
              where e2.entity1.id = e1.id
                and e2.key = :key1 and e2.value = :value1)
  AND exists (select 1 from Entity2 e2 
              where e2.entity1.id = e1.id
                and e2.key = :key2 and e2.value = :value2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select e1.* 
from entity1 e1
join entity2 e21 on e21.e1_id = e1.id and e21.key = :key1 and e21.value = :value1
join entity2 e22 on e22.e1_id = e1.id and e22.key = :key2 and e22.value = :value2
```

Comment: I guess this is a native SQL query.

  This is a appropriate JPQL query which works.
SELECT e1 FROM EsbErrorEntity AS e1
Join e1.props e21
Join e1.props e22
WHERE e21.headerKey = :key1 and e21.headerValue = :value1 
AND   e22.headerKey = :key2 and e21.headerValue = :value2

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
SELECT some_filed FROM Entity1 AS e1 Join e1.props AS p 
WHERE 
(p.key = :key1 and p.value = :value1)
and
(p.key = :key2 and p.value = :value2);
```

Comment: You see, this query won't return anything for key1 <> key2 which is generally the case.

Comment: @Dmitry : I have just try to correct the syntax not logic. Is my query is wrong  ?

Comment: I think yes, even from the point of syntax... [inner] JOIN statement should contain ON clause :)

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, didn't notice the 'JPA' tag. But I still can't understand how your query ensures that two different props have specified values.